# How to connect searchkick (in a Rails app &/ Sidekiq job) to multiple elasticsearch clusters without stomping on global searckick config?

Tags: searchkick

Upon startup my app sets my (?global?) searchkick client to point at my default elasticsearch cluster.

```
 Searchkick.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new(
   hosts:            default_cluster, # this is the list of hosts in my default cluster
   retry_on_failure: true,
 )
```

However, I am upgrading my cluster (again), and while I'd like to be able to have my app read/search from that default cluster,

```
/search?q="some term"
# => 
Model.search("some term")
```

continue to work against the default_cluster

Where it starts to get a bit tricky is that:

1. I'd also like (via some specific ?sidekiq background jobs?) to fill an alternate (alt) cluster's index, something like:

```
Model.connect_to(alternate_cluster) {|client|
  Searchkick.client = client
  Model.reindex
}
```

Without causing all other background jobs to interact with the alternate cluster.

And, of course:

2. I'd like some way to verify that the alternate_cluster is working well (i.e. for search) before making it my default_cluster. And presumably via some admin route:

```
/admin/search?q="some search term"&cluster=alternate

# =>
Model.connect_to(alternate_cluster) {|client|
  Searchkick.client = client
  Model.search("some term")
}
```

And finally:

3. I'd like to avoid having to reconnect before *every* search/reindex action, i.e. I'd prefer not to have the overhead of changing (also because that probably implies that long-running tasks that continue to reconnect to searchkick will be swapping back and-forth from one cluster to the other):

```
Model.search("some term")

# =>

Model.connect_to(alternate_cluster) {|client|
  Searchkick.client = client

Model.search("some term")
}
```

^ I don't want that

FWIW, the best I've been able to come-up with so far is something like:

```
def self.connect_to(current_cluster, &block)
  previous_es_client = Searchkick.client

  current_es_client = Elasticsearch::Client.new(
   hosts:            current_cluster,
   retry_on_failure: true,
  )

  block.call(current_es_client)

  rescue Exception => e
    logger.warn(e)
  ensure
    Searchkick.client = previous_es_client
end
```

But, I suspect that will cause every other interaction within my system (via the same web-worker or other background jobs running in the same background-worker-instance) to (temporarily) point at the alternate cluster.

Thanks in advance for your assistance...